# plot legend appearing in iteratively produced plot, missing colors

Tags: plotting, formatting, legending

I'm trying to have the color of each line show up in the plot legend for the following block of code below, except the corresponding colors for each line of the plot do not show up in the legend. I tried moving the PlotLegends call into "Show" and was also unsuccessful...

```
Da = {0, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 1, 1.2, 1.5};
colorList = ColorData[3, "ColorList"]
gamma2 = 10;
Show[Plot[1 + ((Da[[#]]/(6*gamma2 + 6))*(nu^2 - 1)), {nu, 0, 1}, 
PlotStyle -> colorList[[#]], 
PlotLegends -> "Da=" <> ToString[Da[[#]]]] & /@ 
Range[Length[Da]],
PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0.97, 1}},
PlotLabel -> 
" \[Gamma]=10",
ImageSize -> Large]
```

as seen in the attached image below, the line colors aren't appearing in the legend.
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 4):

Your code can be simplified quite a bit:
Rather than mapping you can take advantage of listability. So

```
1 + ((Da[[#]]/(6*gamma2 + 6))*(nu^2 - 1))& /@ Range[Length[Da]]
```

becomes

```
1 + ((Da/(6*gamma2 + 6))*(nu^2 - 1))
```

And also the plot does not require `Show`

```
Plot[Evaluate[1 + ((Da/(6*gamma2 + 6))*(nu^2 - 1))], {nu, 0, 1},
 PlotStyle -> ColorData[3, "ColorList"], 
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Da = " <> ToString[#] & /@ Da, Right],
 PlotLabel -> " \[Gamma]=10",
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

Note that it could be simplified further by using simply:

```
PlotStyle -> 3,
```

i.e. no need to explicitly mention `ColorData`

Answer (score 1):

You aren't giving `PlotLegends` a way to reference your colors. Try something like this where I have created a `Row` that also references `colorList`:

```
Show[
 Plot[
    1 + ((Da[[#]]/(6*gamma2 + 6))*(nu^2 - 1)), {nu, 0, 1},
    PlotStyle -> colorList[[#]],
    PlotLegends -> Row[{
       Graphics[{colorList[[#]], Line[{{0, 0}, {.5, 0}}]}, 
        ImageSize -> {30, 10}, AspectRatio -> 1/10],
       Style[" Da = " <> ToString[Da[[#]]], "Text"]
       }]
    ] & /@ Range[Length[Da]],
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0.97, 1}},
 PlotLabel -> " \[Gamma]=10",
 ImageSize -> Large
 ]
```

> [image]

Comment: thanks so much! this is really helpful. could you explain how to make the color a line?

Comment: @wiscoYogi added!